# how to create a countdown timer in android?

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I am developing a simple maths app for practicing addition, subtraction, multiplication etc. so far i created, when the user types the answer and press the check button if the answer is the correct a toast will  show "correct answer" else "wrong try again"

I want to include countdown timer showing a 30 second countdown in a `TextView`. If the user presses the check button the timer has to stop/pause & if the answer is the correct answer a toast will  show "correct answer" else wrong try again and the timer should continue till the last second and finally a toast will  show "time up".

Comment: use a `CountDownTimer`?

Answer (score 0):

You will be using the Handler class.

Use the following variables

```
private final int SECOND = 1;
private final int MAX_TIME = 30; // seconds

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private int mRemainingTime = MAX_TIME;
private TextView mTimeText;
```

Call the below inside your onCreate, or whenever you'd like.

```
mTimeText = findViewById(R.id.textview);
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mRemainingTime --;
        updateViews();

        if(mRemainingTime <= 0) {
            onTimeReachedZero();
        } else {
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, SECOND);
        }
    }
}, SECOND);
```

and then your defined methods...

```
private void updateViews() {
    // update your textview
    mTimeText.setText("" + mRemainingTime);
}

private void onTimeReachedZero() {
    // show your toast and do any other handling
}
```